# Leetcode 3Sum problem using hashmap in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, k-sum

For practice, I solved Leetcode [15. 3Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/) question:

> Given an array nums of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in nums such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.

My code pass all testcases from my location but get Time Limit Exceeded from leetcode. Can anyone suggest me how to improve my code?

```
def threeSum(nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: List[List[int]]
    """
    if len(nums) < 3: return []
    len_n, res, n_map, target = len(nums), set(), dict(), 0
    nums.sort()
    for i, n in enumerate(nums):
        for j, c in enumerate(nums[i + 1:], i + 1):
            s = n + c
            n_map[s] = n_map.get(s, []) + [(i, j)]

    for i, n in enumerate(nums):
        s = target - n
        for k in n_map.get(s, []):
            if i > k[1]:
                res.add((nums[i], nums[k[0]], nums[k[1]]))
    return list(map(list, res))
```

Comment: You currently have a small error? typo? in your code: `len_n, res, n_map. target = len(nums), set(), dict(), ` is not actually ok. I am not sure how this is supposed to look like, so please just correct it.

Comment: thank you. updated already..it is typo when i post the code..

Answer (score 3):

I think the current way of solving this problem seems an acceptable, albeit naive, way to solve it, but there are some tweaks that can enhance the readability.

## variables

```
len_n, res, n_map, target = len(nums), set(), dict(), 0
```

is both unclear and unnecessary.

`len_n` is never used, `res` is only used far further in the code

## `collections.defaultdict`

You do a lot of `n_map.get(s, [])`. Simpler would be to define `n_map` as a `collectcions.defaultdict(list)`, and then for example just do `n_map[s].append((i, j))`

## indices

You add `(i, j)` to `n_map`, only to later retrieve them as tuple `k`. It would be easier to use tuple unpacking:

```
for k, n in enumerate(nums): # i is used
    s = target - n
    for i, j in n_map[s]:
        if k > j:
            res.add((nums[k], nums[i], nums[j]))
```

Since you only use `i` and `j` here to retrieve `a` and `b`, why not save them in `n_map` in the first place?

```
n_map = defaultdict(list)
for i, a in enumerate(nums):
    for j, b in enumerate(nums[i + 1 :], i + 1):
        n_map[a + b].append((j, a, b))
res = set()
for k, c in enumerate(nums):
    for j, a, b in n_map[target - c]:
        result = c, a, b
        if k > j:
            ...
```

## `res` and `yield`

Defining `res` as a set is a good choice. I think it is easier to only add the tuple to `res` if it is not present yet, and `yield` it at the same time, instead of returning `list(map(list, res))` at the end

In total this gives:

```
def three_sum_maarten(nums, target=0):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: List[List[int]]In total this gives
    """
    if len(nums) < 3:
        return []
    n_map = defaultdict(list)
    nums = sorted(nums)
    for i, a in enumerate(nums):
        for j, b in enumerate(nums[i + 1 :], i + 1):
            n_map[a + b].append((j, a, b))
    res = set()
    for k, c in enumerate(nums):
        for j, a, b in n_map[target - c]:
            result = c, a, b
            if k > j and result not in res:
                yield [c, a, b]
                res.add(result)
```

With this leetcode boilerplate:

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums: 'List[int]') -> 'List[List[int]]':
        return list(three_sum_maarten(nums))
```

This passes all but one scenario. The scenario it fails is `nums = [0] * 3000`

To tackle this scenario, you can filter all numbers so only maximum 3 of each are present in `nums`. I do this with the help of a `collections.Counter`:

```
def prepare_nums(nums):
    counter = Counter(nums)

    for n, c in sorted(counter.items()):
        yield from [n] * min(c, 3)
```

and then `nums = list(prepare_nums(nums))` instead of `nums = sorted(nums)`

---

## Alternative approach

You make about half of all combinations of 2 numbers in `nums`. One extra bit of knowledge you can use to reduce this is to take into account that at least 1 negative and 1 positive number need to be present in each triplet.

```
counter = Counter(nums)
positives = [i for i in counter if i > 0]
negatives = [i for i in counter if i < 0]

for a, b in product(positives, negatives):
    c = -(a + b)
    if c not in counter:
        continue
    result = a, b, c
```

and then only yield the correct, unique results

```
    result = a, b, c
    if c == a:
        if counter[a] >= 2:
            yield result
    elif c == b:
        if counter[b] >= 2:
            yield result
    elif a > c > b:
        yield result
```

and yield 1 `(0, 0, 0)` triplet if there are 3 or more `0`s present

```
if counter[0] >= 3:
    yield (0, 0, 0)
```

This solution is about 10 times faster, and uses 30 times less memory.

Comment: thank you. the review make so much sense now. However, couple of question for line `    for j, a, b in n_map[target - c]:` what if no key can found on n_map? and can you explain a littit bit about why it is good choice to use yield `yield [c, a, b]` here?

Comment: If there is no element with key `target-c` in `n_map`, this `defaultdict` returns an empty list. The `for`-loop starts iterating over it, but since it's empty, there are no iterations. On your second question, the order of `c, a, b` has no effect

Comment: understand, thank you.. great solution for your alternative approach as well