# Solution to 3Sum problem on Leetcode using HashTable

Tags: python, programming-challenge, hash-map, k-sum

The problem of 3sum is described as:

> Given an array nums of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in nums such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.

Here is my code, am I right to say its complexity is O(N<sup>2</sup>), and how can I further optimize my code? Here I am using HashTable:

```
class Solution(object):      
    def threeSum(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """
        dct = {}
        trip = {}
        triplet = []


        nums_len = len(nums)
        for i in range(nums_len - 1):
            for j in range(i + 1, nums_len):
                key = nums[i] + nums[j]
                if key in dct:
                    if (i in dct[key]):
                        continue
                    dct[key] = dct[key] + [i, j]  # If exists, append more in a bucket
                else:
                    dct[key] = [i, j]

        for k in range(nums_len):
            supplement = -1*nums[k]  # nums[k] = - (nums[i] + num[j])
            if supplement in dct:
                entry = dct[supplement]  #look on the dict
                entry_len = len(entry)
                entry_num = entry_len//2
                for m in range(entry_num):
                    pair = [entry[m*2], entry[m*2+1]]
                    if (k not in pair):
                        candidate = [nums[entry[m*2]], nums[entry[m*2+1]], nums[k]]
                        candidate.sort()
                        key = str(candidate[0]) +  str(candidate[1]) + str(candidate[2])
                        if (key not in trip):
                            trip[key] = True
                            triplet.append(candidate)

        return triplet
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please add a language tag.

Comment: You might get some inspiration from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/213328/35991.

Comment: It is very difficult to optimize when we don't know what language the code is.

Comment: Is `nums` a unique list?

Comment: I am so sorry, the code is Python2, and nums is not a unique list. Should I write some more comments in code to clarify my idea?

Comment: Someone helps me out? I think its O(N^2) but this code can not pass all test cases on leetcode